# Como criar um prefixo para a url usando o spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Aprendi a usar o `spring` fazendo toda a configuração em classes java e agora estou migrando para o `spring boot 2.0.2`.

Gostaria de saber como criar um prefixo na URL que tenha o nome do projeto que funcione como uma base identificadora do mesmo.

Vamos supor que eu tenha um projeto chamado `app-rht`

Quando abrir browser quero de chamar  por

`http://localhost:8080/app-rht/usuario/add`

para adicionar um usuário e não apenas

`http://localhost:8080/usuario/add`

como estou fazendo atualmente em meus projetos usando o spring boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No arquivo application.properties, acrescente a seguinte propriedade:

```
//Se estiver usando Spring Boot 2
server.servlet.contextPath=/app-rht

//Se estiver usando Spring Boot < 2
server.contextPath=/app-rht
```

[Documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24452123/4319922)

Comment: Muito obrigado cara!